# How can I avoid MySQL queries in a FOREACH block when SUM is used on specific criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, foreach

Essentially, what I have *works*, but isn't best practice.

Here's my current output, which is what I want, but I'm wondering if I can query this data with a single (albeit complex) query instead of running 5-10 separate queries. (3-7 in a foreach statement, which I'd like to eliminate.)

[image: Example]

If I could pull all the data in one query, place it in an array, and then pull that into the table respectively, that would be more efficient.

But I'm not very experienced with MySQL and unsure how to query multiple SUMs of specific data that requires specific WHERE criteria...

Here's an example of my tables: (the actual tables are more complex, but I think this is simplified such that it's understandable.)

```
+-------------------------------------+
|              crop_plans             |
+-------------------------------------+
| ID | advisor_id | acres | crop_year |
+----+------------+-------+-----------+
| 1  | 3          | 1000  | 2018      |
+----+------------+-------+-----------+
| 2  | 1          | 1500  | 2019      |
+----+------------+-------+-----------+
| 3  | 2          | 300   | 2017      |
+----+------------+-------+-----------+
| 4  | 2          | 600   | 2018      |
+----+------------+-------+-----------+
| 5  | 3          | 800   | 2017      |
+----+------------+-------+-----------+

+---------------------+
|        users        |
+---------------------+
| user_id | full_name |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | Dude A    |
+---------+-----------+
| 2       | Dude B    |
+---------+-----------+
| 3       | Dude C    |
+---------+-----------+

+----------------------+
|       advisors       |
+----------------------+
| advisor_id | user_id |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | 1       |
+------------+---------+
| 2          | 2       |
+------------+---------+
| 3          | 3       |
+------------+---------+
```

Here's my queries and thinking, followed by the code:

First, I pull get the advisor's name (and ID):

```
SELECT ad.advisor_id AS this_advisor_id, ua.full_name AS full_name
FROM advisors AS ad 
JOIN users AS ua ON ad.user_id = ua.user_id 
WHERE advisor_id > 1;
```

*(yes, leaving out the first one)*

Then for each of those results, I query a SUM of the acres for a given year where the advisor is the advisor in this "row":

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT SUM(acres) AS current_year_acres 
        FROM crop_plans
        WHERE crop_year = ? AND advisor_id = ?
    ) a CROSS JOIN  (
        SELECT SUM(acres) AS last_year_acres 
        FROM crop_plans 
        WHERE crop_year = ? AND advisor_id = ?
    ) b CROSS JOIN  (
        SELECT SUM(acres) AS year_before_acres
        FROM crop_plans 
        WHERE crop_year = ? AND advisor_id = ?
    ) c;
```

And then finally I query the totals: (not advisor dependant)

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT SUM(acres) AS current_year_acres 
        FROM crop_plans
        WHERE crop_year = ?
    ) a CROSS JOIN  (
        SELECT SUM(acres) AS last_year_acres 
        FROM crop_plans 
        WHERE crop_year = ?
    ) b CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(acres) AS year_before_acres 
        FROM crop_plans 
        WHERE crop_year = ?
    ) c
```

And with those results I display them with PHP, etc. so that it looks like what you see in the screenshot above.

Here's the full (working, but not ideal) code:

```
<?php
echo '<table class="table table-striped table-hover dashboard"><thead><tr>';
echo '<th>Advisor</th><th>'.$current_year.'</th><th>'.$last_year.'</th><th>'.$year_before.'</th>'; // Header
echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

$sql_retreive = $con->prepare("SELECT ad.advisor_id AS this_advisor_id, ua.full_name AS full_name FROM advisors AS ad JOIN users AS ua ON ad.user_id = ua.user_id WHERE advisor_id > 1;");
$sql_retreive->execute();
$result = $sql_retreive->get_result(); 
if($result->num_rows >0 ){
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
   extract($row); // assigns respective values
   echo '<tr>'; // start row
   echo '<td><!--'.$this_advisor_id.'-->'.$full_name.'</td>'; // First column

            // query database for each advisor
            $sql_retreive_in = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT SUM(acres) AS current_year_acres FROM crop_plans WHERE crop_year = ? AND advisor_id = ?) a CROSS JOIN  (SELECT SUM(acres) AS last_year_acres FROM crop_plans WHERE crop_year = ? AND advisor_id = ?) b CROSS JOIN  (SELECT SUM(acres) AS year_before_acres FROM crop_plans WHERE crop_year = ? AND advisor_id = ?) c;");
            $bind_process_in = $sql_retreive_in->bind_param('sisisi',$current_year,$this_advisor_id,$last_year,$this_advisor_id,$year_before,$this_advisor_id); 
            $sql_retreive_in->execute();
            $result_in = $sql_retreive_in->get_result(); 
            if($result_in->num_rows >0 ){
                while($row_in=$result_in->fetch_assoc()){
                extract($row_in); // assigns respective values
                echo '<td>'.format($current_year_acres,'lunit').'</td><td>'.format($last_year_acres,'lunit').'</td><td>'.format($year_before_acres,'lunit').'</td>'; // Remaining columns
                    } // end of inside while
                } // end of inside num_rows >0

        echo '</tr>'; // end row
        } // end of while
    } // end of num_rows >0

// Final totals line
echo '<tr>'; // start row
echo '<td> Total</td>'; // First column

    $sql_retreive = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT SUM(acres) AS current_year_acres FROM crop_plans WHERE crop_year = ?) a CROSS JOIN  (SELECT SUM(acres) AS last_year_acres FROM crop_plans WHERE crop_year = ?) b CROSS JOIN  (SELECT SUM(acres) AS year_before_acres FROM crop_plans WHERE crop_year = ?) c");
    $bind_process = $sql_retreive->bind_param('sss',$current_year,$last_year,$year_before); 
    $sql_retreive->execute();
    $result = $sql_retreive->get_result(); 
    if($result->num_rows >0 ){
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
       extract($row); // assigns respective values
       echo '<td>'.format($current_year_acres,'lunit').'</td><td>'.format($last_year_acres,'lunit').'</td><td>'.format($year_before_acres,'lunit').'</td>'; // Remaining columns
            } // end of while
        } // end of num_rows >0

    echo '</tr>'; // end row
    // echo "<tr><td colspan='100%'></td></tr>"; 
    echo "</tbody></table>";
    ?>
```

I'd be very grateful for any good suggestions on how I could eliminate the query in the foreach statement (by collecting all those values in advance with a query and putting them into an array.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a single query, using *conditional aggregation* :

```
SELECT 
    ua.full_name AS Advisor,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cp.year = 2017 THEN cp.acres ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Acres_2017,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cp.year = 2018 THEN cp.acres ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Acres_2018,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cp.year = 2019 THEN cp.acres ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Acres_2019
FROM advisors AS ad 
INNER JOIN users AS ua ON ad.user_id = ua.user_id 
INNER JOIN crop_plans AS cp WHERE cp.advisor_id = ad.advisor_id
WHERE ad.advisor_id > 1
GROUP BY ad.advisor_id, ua.full_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Total', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cp.year = 2017 THEN cp.acres ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN cp.year = 2018 THEN cp.acres ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN cp.year = 2019 THEN cp.acres ELSE 0 END)
FROM crop_plans AS cp 
WHERE cp.advisor_id > 1
```

The first query computes the total acres for each advisor and year, using conditional aggregation to pivot the resultset. Please note that this only works over a fixed set of columns (if you need to change the year window, the query must be modified).

The first resultset is `UNION`ed with a second query, that computes the totals by years, basically using the same technique.

Comment: Precisely what I was after. I have a bunch of similar  queries so now I can use this concept. Much appreciated @GMB. Initially I was getting some minor errors when trying to process the query, so I've edited the answer just to clarify that to anyone else who may benefit from this.